# Error: Atropos is not defined error after hosted

Tags: git, github, local, git-remote, defined

I'm working with Atropos js library.It works perfect in local.But when I try to open in remote after hosting in github.Its not working.And I have installed Atropos using npm.

here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/atropos/atropos.min.css"/>
<head>
<body>

   //my code goes here 
   
   <script src="node_modules/atropos/atropos.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      const myAtropos = Atropos({
        el: ".my-atropos",
        highlight: false,
        shadow: true,
        alwaysActive: true,
        shadowScale: 1,
        shadowOffset:20
      });
    </script>
</body>
</hmtl>
```

Error : Atropos is not defined.

Comment: I don't think this line will work in the hosted instance: **<script src="node_modules/atropos/atropos.min.js"></script>** Maybe try replacing that  link with a link to a CDN, at least as a test: https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/atropos